# Do there exist functions $\phi$ and $A$ such that $\vec E$ satisfies the Helmholtz Theorem $\vec E = -\nabla \phi + \nabla \times \vec A$?

Tags: electromagnetism, mathematical-physics, potential, vector-fields

Helmholtz Decomposition theorem stats:

"Let $\vec F$ be a vector field on a bounded domain $V$ in $\mathbb R^3$, which is twice continuously differentiable, and let $S$ be the surface that encloses the domain $V$. Then $\vec F$ can be decomposed into a curl-free component and a divergence-free component"

$$ \vec F = -\nabla \phi +  \nabla \times \vec A$$

It is easy to see that 
$\phi$ is equal to $V$ in electrostatic where $V$ is the electric potential. Can someone tell me what  $\vec A$ would represent?

Is there a similiar analogy for $\vec B$?

Comment: The term you're looking for is ["vector potential"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_potential#Magnetic_vector_potential)

Comment: Interesting, why would this term appear in the equation for electric field? I wonder. And why is it zero in electrostatics?

Comment: It appears due to [Maxwell's equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell's_equations). Electrostatics implicitly assume that the magnetic field just does not exist, hence $\mathbf A$ not appearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\nabla\times\vec{A}$ is the *solenoidal* component of the vector field: it is the divergenceless component.

A good way to intuitively visualise the Helmholtz theorem is to think in Fourier space, so that all fields become their Fourier transforms. In this visualisation, $\nabla\times \vec{E}$ is the component of the Fourier transform that is at right angles to the wavevector. Then the differential operations become dot and cross products with the position in Fourier space *i.e.* the wavevector of plane wave component. So, instead of $\vec{E}(\vec{r})$, we have now a field $\tilde{\vec{E}}(\vec{k})$ specifying the superposition weight (amplitude) of a plane wave component $\exp(i\,\vec{k}\cdot\,\vec{r})$ in the Fourier decomposition of the field. The Fourier transforms of the following $\nabla$ operations on vector and scalar fields  $\vec{E}(\vec{r})$ and $\phi(\vec{r})$ are:

$$\nabla\phi(\vec{r}) \leftrightarrow i\,\vec{k}\,\tilde{\phi}(\vec{k})$$
$$\nabla\cdot\vec{E}(\vec{r}) \leftrightarrow i\,\vec{k}\,\cdot\tilde{\vec{E}}(\vec{k})$$
$$\nabla\times\vec{E}(\vec{r}) \leftrightarrow i\,\vec{k}\,\times\tilde{\vec{E}}(\vec{k})$$

where the tilde quantities are the Fourier transforms. So, at each point in space, $\tilde{\vec{E}}(\vec{k})$ resolve the vector into unique components parallel to and orthogonal to the wavevector (the position vector in Fourier space):

$$\begin{array}{lcl}\tilde{\vec{E}}(\vec{k}) &=& \tilde{E}_\parallel(\vec{k})\,\frac{\vec{k}}{|\vec{k}|}+\tilde{E}_\perp(\vec{k})\,\frac{\vec{k}\times \tilde{\vec{E}}(\vec{k})}{|\vec{k}|\,|\tilde{\vec{E}}(\vec{k})|}\\&=&-i\,\left(\mathfrak{F}(\nabla.\vec{E}) \,\hat{k} + \mathfrak{F}(\nabla\times\vec{E})\right)\end{array}$$

where $\mathfrak{F}$ is the Fourier transform. The curl is the component of the field at right angles to the unit radius $\hat{k}$ (modulo the scaling constant $i$), since $\hat{k}\cdot(\vec{k}\times \tilde{\vec{E}})=0$ and the divergence is the component along the unit radius $\hat{k}$

Comment: Hmm I thought the fourier transform had no effect on spatial operators i.e. $d/d_z$ is unchanged

Comment: @IllegalImmigrant No, that's only true if the derivative is with respect to a non-transform variable: otherwise you have the fundamental rule $\mathrm{d}_x\,\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\,k\,x}\, f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = i\,k\,F(k)$.

Answer (score 2):

$\vec{A}$ is the vector potential. $\vec{E}$ is equal to $-\nabla\phi$ only in the electrostatic case. If the electric field varies with time, we have
\begin{equation}
\nabla\times\vec{E} = -\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t}
\end{equation}
Since $\nabla\cdot\vec{B}$ is always zero, $\vec{B}$ is written as a curl of another field, called the vector potential. That is $\vec{B} = \nabla\times\vec{A}$. Putting this in the above equation, we get
\begin{equation}
\nabla\times\left(\vec{E} + \frac{\partial\vec{A}}{\partial t}\right) = 0
\end{equation}
Curl of a field is zero means that it can be expressed as a gradient of a scalar field. In this case, it is $-\phi$. That is,
\begin{equation}
\vec{E} + \frac{\partial\vec{A}}{\partial t} = -\nabla{\phi}
\end{equation}

One can surely use Helmholtz theorem for magnetic field as well and write it as $\vec{B} = -\nabla\psi + \nabla\times\vec{A}$, where $\psi$ is the magnetic scalar potential. It is non-zero only if $\nabla\times\vec{B} = 0$. (Please note that $\psi$ is usually defined using the $\vec{H}$ field. However, the idea is applicable to $\vec{B}$ field as well. You can refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_potential#Magnetic_scalar_potential for additional information.)

Comment: Hi is the vector potential a physical or mathematical quantity?

Comment: I do not know if the vector potential is truly a physical quantity. I used to think that the Aharanov-Bohm effect indicates that it is indeed a physical quantity and not just a mathematical convenience. However, it appears that not every one agrees with this view. See, for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect#Potentials_vs_fields.